# Flutter create file in download folder

Tags: android, flutter, file, storage

In my app I need to download some bills.
On IOS my users can easily find them when app is closed because it is stored in a dedicated folder easily findable. I achieve that with getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() from path_provider and the following option in plist :

```
<key>UISupportsDocumentBrowser</key>
<true/>
```

In android, downloaded files aren't put inside the download folder but inside the app data folder which is hard for a simple user to understand how to go in. What can I do to put bills (pdf) inside the Android Download folder ?
I use for the moment the method getExternalStorageDirectory() from path_provider for Android.

Comment: `In android, downloaded file aren't put inside the download folder but inside the app data folder` No. Who is doing that you said? You can download to public Download or Documents folder and to subfolders of them.

Comment: @blackapps, I've a Xiaomi : for example files are created inside this folder :  
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/my.app.id/files/.    
I'm looking for a way to put files inside the right download folder, maybe something like /storage/download.

Comment: You are complainig about your code and your code does it. Change it to download to the right storage location. And /storage/download does not exist. I was talking about /storage/emulated/0/Download.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to get the pathname of the current phone Download folder...
I presume Android phone Brands can maybe have a particular download path and not by default /storage/download ?

Comment: @blackapps /storage/emulated/0/Download is a 'default' path and is common to all Android phone brands ? (Samsung / xiaomi / honor / huawei etc) ?

Comment: Does not have to be that always. Use getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) to get the actual path.

Answer (score 4):

Based on @blackapps responses, I used the following hard coded path in Android and fallback to getExternalStorageDirectory() if folder didn't exist.

```dart
final Directory directory = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download');
if (!await directory.exists()) directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
```